# Trigger or Force Redraw or Re-Render of WebView

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

My understanding is that WebView's `PictureListener.onNewPicture()` is called whenever the already loaded page finished rendering (or re-rendering in case certain events make the WebKit engine re-calculate page layout).

I also (think that I) understand that those WebView renders are controlled internally in WebView and ordinarily I wouldn't care how they are being generated.

However, for a certain function in my app, I need to trigger an extra `PictureListener.onNewPicture()` **without** re-loading the url (i.e. no `reload()` or `loadUrl()`).

Essentially, what I am looking for is a function like repaint() or redraw() or some other mechanism that only generate one more `PictureListener.onNewPicture()` and that's it (without the slowness and overhead associated with re-loading data).

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `requestLayout()` function. 
not sure if it will do what you want, but it worth a try.